# NoMethodError when method is defined

Tags: scala

I'm following along to video 3.1 of the Coursera Scala class, and cannot get my Scala worksheet to recognize that a contains method is indeed defined for the Empty class:

```
package objsets

abstract class IntSet {
  def incl(x:Int): IntSet
  def contains(x:Int): Boolean
}


class Empty extends IntSet {
def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, new Empty, new Empty)
}

class NonEmpty (elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
    def contains(x: Int):Boolean =
        if (x < elem) left contains x
        else if (x > elem) right contains x
        else true

    def incl(x:Int):IntSet =
        if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x,right)
        else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
        else this
}

object Video1 {
    val empty = new Empty
    empty.contains(2)
}
```

At the end of object Video1, when I call .contains(), I get the following error in a Scala IDE worksheet:

`NoSuchMethodError: objsets.Empty.contains(I)Z`

Comment: Is Video1 in the same file? If not, show your imports. Also check if everything compiles fine and IDE does not report any errors.

Comment: I'm not taking it, but I'm pretty certain a comment on another question suggested that questions about the course should *not* be posted outside the coursera course boards.

Comment: Notwithstanding the previous comment, it works find for me in the REPL.